# Drawing into a loaded UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, draw

I have a couple of questions.

I have a loaded UIImage and i would like to:

1st - draw another image onto my loaded UIImage

2nd - draw a line (with color and thickness) onto my loaded UIImage

I would greatly appreciate if you would come up with some basic stuff, i'm still a noob :)

Comment: What is your goal here? Do you want a new UIImage that contains the result of all of this drawing? Or do you simply want to display a line over the two overlaid images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's another alternative and it comes using core-graphics.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);
UIImage *bottomImage = ...;
CGRect bottomImageRect = ...;
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -bottomImageRect.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, bottomImageRect, bottomImage.CGImage);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
UIImage *topImage = ...;
CGRect topImageRect = ...;
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -topImageRect.size.height);
CGContextDrawImage(context, topImageRect, topImage.CGImage);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGPoint origin = ...;
CGPoint end = ...;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, origin.x, origin.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, end.x, end.y);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whatever].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**EDIT:**
Changed the code a little so that images are not inverted

Comment: I forgot about that ... images are drawn with an inverted coordinate system. check edit for the fix